# variable being passed through parameters not updated

Tags: python, tkinter

The user selects a goal which then changes the background colour scheme. I have it working, however when a new function is ran, the colour scheme reverts back to the original.

When the goal is selected, one of these functions gets called (depending on which goal is selected.

```
def Get_Fit():
    canvas.delete("all")
    goal = "fit"
    Overlay(goal)
    Bottom(goal)
```

Those functions determine the goal, and then call the overlay function (which is resonsible for the colour scheme).

```
def Overlay(goal):
    colour = Goal(goal)
    canvas.create_oval(-2000, 50, 1000, 2000, fill='gray33', outline=colour, width=4)
    canvas.create_oval(-300, 1600, 4000, 300, fill="gray21", outline=colour, width=4)
    canvas.create_text(500, 100, text="EZ FITNESS", font=font3, fill = "gray80")
```

This `overlay` function calls another function called `goal`. `goal` is responsible for determining the colours in the colour scheme.

```
def Goal(goal):
    if goal == "fit":
        colour="#00e5ff"
    elif goal == "weight":
        colour="#ff00e5"
    elif goal == "strong":
        colour = "#d60000"
    else:
        colour="#ff5d00"
    return colour
```

Everytime the overlay function is called, it is called as follows:

```
Overlay(goal)
```

Now when i select a goal, the colour scheme changes as it is supposed to. However as soon as I run a new function (in this example `account`) the colour scheme reverts back to the original colour. Any ideas why? Here is the code for `Account`

```
def Account():
    canvas.delete("all")
    Bottom(goal)
    Overlay(goal)

    startingweight_label = Label(canvas, width=15, height=1, text="Starting Weight: ", font=font2, bg="gray33", fg="white", relief = "raised", borderwidth=2)
    canvas_startingweight_label = canvas.create_window(475, 350, window=startingweight_label)

    startingweight_entry = Entry(root, width = 10, bg="gray30")
    canvas_startingweight_entry = canvas.create_window(600, 350, window=startingweight_entry)
```

Here are some pictures
Picture A demonstrates what happens after the Get Fit goal is selected. This works well.

Picture B demonstrates what happens after the get fit goal is selected and then after Account is ran. As you can see, the colour scheme reverts.
[image: A]

[image: B]

Comment: goal is a string and you are changing it inside the functions, but then you are not returning it, so the changes done inside the functions will disappear when exiting the function

Comment: How do i structure the code then? Could you provide a solution?

Comment: Just do `goal = Bottom(goal)` and `goal = Overlay(goal)` in your Account function

Comment: `canvas.delete("all")`  ??? `canvas.itemconfig(..........)` !!

Comment: No i use canvas.delete("all") everywhere. I reload the function though which should get it working.

Comment: in regard to goal = Overlay(goal) - it says goal is referenced before assignment

Comment: Is there any way i could do canvas.delete("all except Overlay() and Bottom")

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue!

The problem was that the changes made to `goal` were staying local to the function. What i had to do return goal so that all changes made in the function were made to the other functions. I did this simply by globalising the variable. You need to be careful when globalising variables, however in this scenario i believe it is ok!

```
def Get_Fit():
    canvas.delete("all")
    goal = "fit"
    global goal
    Overlay(goal)
    Bottom(goal)
```